# Why is my Github page responding with 404?

Tags: r, github, r-markdown, github-pages

I'm trying to launch a Github website.However, when I go to publish, I receive a 404 error message:

"File not found. The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file.If this is your site, make sure that the filename case matches the URL.For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file."

I have an index file, and the address matches the repository name.

Comment: I'm not a gh-pages guru, but you are going to have to provide more information than that. If it's a public repo, I suggest you start by providing the URL to the repo on which your gh-pages will be based.

Comment: I finally figured it out. Thank you for the response!